# calculate critical value for The Spearman Rank Correlation Coefficient

Tags: excel, statistics, hypothesis-test

i know formula for calculation  The Spearman Rank Correlation Coefficient, here is it
[image]

my question is :  how to calculate critical value? i know that  T test can work for this case, but  for instance  for the following data

[image]

to find  critical value for n=8 and alpha=0.05, i can use function Tinv , but it  does  not  match critical value from table , which is given here
[image]

please tell me which formula in excel  can  find critical value for  this case?

Comment: What kind of table is that? That is not the critical value for the t-distribution with `alpha = 0.05` and `n = 8`. Those critical values would be 1.86 (one-sided alpha) or 2.360 (two-sided)